# How can I join tables using only DAX?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, business-intelligence, dax

Goal:
Display column "C_qty" in the table A using DAX.

Problem:
How can I do it by using DAX only?

Info:
- No usage of SQL code!
- The relationship between tables is established in VS 2010 with an SSAS instance in tabular mode.

```
data model

table A
------
PK_A_nr    A_qty         
1           5
2           3
3           2


table B
--------
PK_B_nr    FK_A_nr     FK_C_nr     
1                1        1   
2                2        2
3                3        3


table C
--------
PK_C_nr    C_qty           
1            5
2            3
3            2
```

Comment: Can you add SQL code that leads you to desired results?

Answer (score 0):

looks like a many to many scenario...take a look at this:

http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/optimize-many-to-many-calculation-in-dax-with-summarize-and-cross-table-filtering/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PowerPivot you can create a relationship between these two tables.
If you only want to use a DAX query, you can use the [RELATED DAX function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634202.aspx).